# How to set scheduler task in spring to run every 1 minutes

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

now I have this configuration my my scheduler:

```
<task:scheduled ref="task" method="run" cron="0 45 22 * * *" />
```

when this task is executed ? and how I can change it to do this task every minute

Answer (score 111, accepted):

This task is executed at 22:45:00 every day, every week, every month.

To execute a task every minute, use

```
0 * * * * *
```

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is correct for spring. Other than that, one should be careful whether the target system uses 6 or 5-digits cron.

With 5-digits-crons

`0 * * * *` schedules to be run *"at minute 0"* (hence every hour).

The correct answer in this case should be either

**`* * * * *`**

or

**`*/1 * * * *`**

Also see: [Spring cron vs normal cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887822/spring-cron-vs-normal-cron)

Comment: 0 * * * * * is at second 0. You missed one star.

Comment: Actually, it depends.. :-)
Officially cron has 5 digits, whereas some cron implementations (4th BSD edition on Linux or the nncron deamon for Windows) support a sixth digit. (Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: I know it, but i'm talking about Spring. It uses 6 digits cron.

Comment: This answer is wrong. I updated the question's tags.

Comment: This gives error
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'schedule': Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 5 in "*/1 * * * *")

Comment: As mentioned, for spring cron expressions do not ofollow the UNIX cron expressions, thus you should use 6 digits when using spring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887822/spring-cron-vs-normal-cron