# How to start a task every minute

Tags: spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have tried this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * ? * *")
    public void sendMessageFromDB() throws JsonProcessingException {
}
```

but it does not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set scheduler task in spring to run every 1 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097771/how-to-set-scheduler-task-in-spring-to-run-every-1-minutes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `*` or `0/1` for minutes, not `*/1`.

Also, consider using `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60_000)` or `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 60_000)` (or `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1, timeUnit = MINUTES)` etc.) instead. The difference between `fixedDelay` and `fixedRate` is that *delay* specifies the time between task execution (i.e. one minute after the task previously finished), and the *rate* specifies the interval the task is started (i.e. every minute).